# how to copy downloaded file in tmp folder of aws lambda to s3 specific folder within bucket

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I download image from S3(Lambda trigger) and did some operations on image and saved to aws lambda tmp folder then I want to copy that image to same bucket and to specific folder.How can I do That(I don't want to upload into another bucket)
I want implement with python boro3 or any otherway to download image to specific folder do some image anupulation ,save,copy to other folder of s3 within bucket

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you'll want to bypass saving the image to /tmp; have your code write the object wherever you want it to wind up (same bucket or different bucket, it doesn't much matter) via [boto3's put action](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.put).